# hibernate generation for dynamic map

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to generate hbm.xml files to support the dynamic map mode of Hibernate. When I run hbm2hbmxml my classes are generated with the *name* attribute instead of the *entity-name* attribute. When I try to use dynamic map, Hibernate fails to load data from the DB because it cannot find the class. I can manually change the it from *name* to *entity-name* and it works.

The actual output is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="MyEntity" table="MyEntity" schema="dbo" catalog="MyDB">
    ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The necessary output should be:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="MyEntity" table="MyEntity" schema="dbo" catalog="MyDB">
    ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My hibernate.properties file contains:

```
hibernate.default_entity_mode=dynamic-map
```

I am running hbm2hbmxml using hibernate3-maven-plugin version 2.2.

I would like some help configuring the hbm2hbmxml plugin such that it generates my classes with the *entity-name* attribute.

Thanks for the help.